# Problem with $PATH environment variable in VS-Code (WSL2)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, homebrew, wsl-2

Anything Homebrew related stopped working in VS Code bash terminal. I could find out that this is probably related to $PATH environment variable as `echo $Path` in VS Code misses anything related to "linuxbrew"

`/home/tfendt/.vscode-server/bin/f4af3cbf5a99787542e2a30fe1fd37cd644cc31f/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:`

while `echo $PATH` in terminal outside VS-Code

`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

shows the correct paths and everything is working as expected.

As far as I can tell, these are the only differences in `$Path`.

Setup:

- WSL2-Ubuntu
- Homebrew on Linux 3.3.3
- VS Code 1.62.1 with Remote-WSL extension

I have recently updated to VS Code 1.62.1 and Homebrew 3.3.3

As this was working out of the box before, I would like to find out what is causing the different behaviour now. I'm not sure if this is a VS Code issue, WSL-related or if I need to have a look at my Homebrew-Setup. As this goes to deep for my still basic knowledge of anything WSL and VS Code related, any suggestions or hints for further research are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about Homebrew but those paths seem to belong to different system users.

Comment: You should do the work of listing the differences between both PATH values.  Most, if not all users, will just pass over your question because of the super long values you put here.

Comment: I tried to improve the question, thanks @Nic3500 for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a bug introduced in VS Code 1.62.1:

> After updating from 1.62.0 to 1.62.1, the full shell environment under WSL2 isn't loaded.

This seems solved as of now in 1.62.2

Further information:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136791